# RecyclerView not display all data when submiting list repeatedly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-binding-adapter

I am creating Notes app which display user Notes from local database. The app works great, but when I try to search (query) for notes multiple times, some data do not get displayed.

ScreenShot of app:

- [Actual data displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtJpi.png)
- [Data not displayed after repeated search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OywJR.png)

NotesViewModel

```
class NotesViewModel(private val database: NotesDao) : ViewModel() {
    fun searchNotes(string: String) = database.searchNote(string)
}
```

NotesFragment

```
binding.searchEditText.doOnTextChanged { text, _, _, _ ->
    notesViewModel.searchNotes("%$text%").observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
        adapter.submitList(it)
        Log.v("NotesFragment: ", it.toString())           //Log return expected data
    })
}
```

NotesAdapter

```
class NotesAdapter(private val clickListener: NoteClickListener) : ListAdapter<Notes, NotesAdapter.NotesViewHolder>(NotesDiffCallBack()) {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NotesViewHolder {
        return NotesViewHolder.from(parent)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NotesViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(clickListener, item)
    }
    
    class NotesViewHolder private constructor(private val binding: ListItemNotesBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(clickListener: NoteClickListener, item: Notes) {
            binding.note = item
            binding.clickListener = clickListener
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }
        .......
    }
}
```

BindingUtil

```
@BindingAdapter("noteTitle")
fun TextView.setNoteTitle(item: Notes?) {
    item?.let {
        Log.v("BindingUtil ", "title -> "+ it.noteTitle)     // Log return expected data
        when (it.noteTitle.isEmpty()) {
            true -> visibility = View.GONE
            false -> text = item.noteTitle
        }
    }
}
```

list_item_notes.xml

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="note"
        type="com.example.notes.db.Notes" />
<data/>
...
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/note_title_textview"
    app:noteTitle="@{note}" />
```

NotesDiffCallBack in NotesAdapter

```
class NotesDiffCallBack : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Notes>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Notes, newItem: Notes): Boolean {
        return oldItem.noteId == newItem.noteId
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Notes, newItem: Notes): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}
```

The 'note' data returned by database is correct.
Even the Log.v() shows correct 'note' data in both 'NotesFragment' and 'BindingUtil',
but do not gets displayed over UI.
This is really annoying. Please help !!

Comment: Share your diffcallback

Comment: shared, diffcallback @Praveen asked for

Comment: Check your observing list `it` is different with list that `adapter` already has. If you create new `ArrayList<Notes>(it)` in observe and do like this `submitList(ArrayList<Notes>(it))`, it may diffUtill work. DiffUtill works when applied different reference object.

Comment: nope, it did not worked either @liveAnyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check which of these block inside `when` statement is getting called `true` or `false`

If it executes `false` as expected then try to set

`visibilty = View.VISIBLE` inside `false` block

Comment: I wonder why recyclerview behave unusual sometimes ?

Comment: @HimanshuSharma It's not unusual behavior, it's the default behavior of the recycler view. Recycler view reuses the inflated items on the screen for displaying data, so When you are setting the visibility of one of the title gone, and after that when recycler view is using that same view for a title whose visibility is visible, then it's visibility is gone too because it was set GONE earlier but was never set visible again.

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling notifyDataSetChanged() after calling submitList()?

Comment: No, I think diffUtils handle such change in list, so no need for notifyDataSetChanged(). Its UI which is not working sometimes. RecyclerView list is updated correctly.